# Coverity issue + snprintf usage in C++

Tags: c++

To fix the below coverity error. Here for second parameter size should I use
sizeof(empID)-1  or sizeof(empID) ?  should I subtract 1 for removing null character? 
ex:

```
char  empID[8] ;                
snprintf(empID,sizeof(empID)-1, "S%05d", (char)pManager -> GetEmpID( groupID, levelID ) ) ;
```

Coverity output:

> Calling risky function (SECURE_CODING) [VERY RISKY]. Using "sprintf"
>   can cause a buffer overflow when done incorrectly. Because sprintf()
>   assumes an arbitrarily long string, callers must be careful not to
>   overflow the actual space of the destination. Use snprintf() instead,
>   or correct precision specifiers.

Comment: Why not read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)? It's very clear there.

Comment: The Coverity report is on code that you are not displaying.   Is it even relevant to your question, which seems to be "How do I use snprintf() the answer to which probably *is* "read the fine manual"

Answer (score 1):

> The functions **snprintf**() and **vsnprintf**() write at most *size* bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to *str*.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf

So no need to subtract 1, the size already includes the null terminator.

Comment: BTW in someplaces I saw that it was used sizeof(str)-1 for size. Generally in which circumstances does it needs to subtract "-1".

Comment: @Sudhakar: you're probably thinking of strncpy()

Comment: Which is a horrible function anyway because it doesn't always place a null terminator at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you have to subtract 1. I tested simply with this

```
 void main(){
     char ch_1[5];
     strcpy(ch_1, "1234");
     snprintf(ch_1, sizeof(ch_1), "abcdefg");
     printf("ch_1=%s\n", ch_1);
 }
```

`sizeof(ch_1)` returns `5` here. `snprintf` automatically subtracts one i.e. it interprets this as "copy `5-1=4` characters and at 5th position put null terminator".

The result is ch_1=abcd